# How to run Angular 4 production code without server

Tags: angular

I have dist folder created by angular cli. Now, I want to run that files without providing any server.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <base href="./">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="styles.076e9918da4cedd3d6c1.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.44e099ae9c80ebe794de.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.aa13f035adb29aecad16.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.5a179b7fcba087187492.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.1b6029e74c79858144e5.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

In case of `<base href ="/">` , I didn't get js and others bundles files in index.html.
If I change `<base href ="/">` to `<base href ="./">` , then get following 
error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///root/Downloads/Client%20demo%20project/dist/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL 'file:///root/Downloads/Client%20demo%20project/dist/index.html'.
Error: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///root/Downloads/Client%20demo%20project/dist/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL 'file:///root/Downloads/Client%20demo%20project/dist/index.html'.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without providing any server"? You want to load it into the browser directly from the disk? Chrome has several security restrictions and prevents several things when files are loaded from disk instead of from a server. There isn't much Angular can do.

Comment: `<base href ="/">` is used by the route,you can read this [doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#base-href)

Answer (score 0):

TO execute your file over the internet , on some domain you must have to use a server . Either it is Express server , lite-server or anything.
If you want to integrate Angular 4 .

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ng build --prod --base-href ./` and Ex. Microsoft Edge you will be OK